# Tangent planes and why the normal vector pointed in the opposite direction?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

[image]

[image]

These two methods are giving us the same tangent plane but why did we get normal vectors pointed in the opposite direction?

Comment: Given two real vectors $a,b$ we have $a \times b = - b \times a$. If you change the order in the last method, you will get the same direction as the first normal vector.

Comment: ok, so this doesn't really matter too much in this case right?

Comment: In some cases it is more relevant that you get the normal vector in a specific direction (if you working with manifolds and want calculate some integral, for example). But if you interest is just to figure out the normal vector, tangent plan or something like that, the direction is not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

It all comes down to the boundary defined (clockwise or counterclockwise) and then you choose the direction.